# how to verify file signature by client PGP

Tags: windows, key-management, pgp, digital-signature, gnupg

Currently working on verifying and signing a file via GNUPG, given that I've already signed a file, given the clients the .sig and public key, is there a way for a client to verify the file without downloading any additional software? Currently using Cryptophane from GNUPG http://www.gnupg.org/related_software/frontends.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my experience, additional software are required.